# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO Type Conversion Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-insert

I am executing a query in PyCharm connected to a PostgreSQL database. Here is the code that's generating the error:

```
sql_query = '''INSERT INTO "daily_performance_metrics"."employee_transactions" 
("WarehouseName", "Date", "EmployeeName", "00:00", "00:15", "00:30", "00:45", "01:00", "01:15", "01:30", "01:45", "02:00", "02:15", "02:30", "02:45", "03:00", "03:15", "03:30", "03:45", "04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00", "05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45", "07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", "08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", "22:15", "22:30", "22:45", "23:00", "23:15", "23:30", "23:45", "ReceiveRate", "PutAwayRate", "PickRate", "PackRate", "ShipRate", "receiveptp", "putawayptp", "pickptp", "packptp","TOT") 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT name_date_warehouse 
DO UPDATE SET "22:13" = EXCLUDED."22:13";'''

values = tuple(value for key, value in dictionary.items())
lock.acquire(True)
postgres_cursor.execute(sql_query, values)
```

Here's what I get when I print the values tuple:

('PDC Lathrop-Christopher', '05/15/2019', 'Paola Urrutia', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Here are the values in the "values" tuple thats passed in the execute call:

('PDC Lathrop-Christopher', '05/15/2019', 'Paola Urrutia', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

The datatypes for the 0.0s are float and the datatypes for all other fields is str.

The error I'm getting is: "not all arguments converted during string formatting" Any ideas what might be wrong with the syntax?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The double quotes are correct here, they are column names

Comment: Please format your sql statements over multiple lines, this is just unreadable.

Comment: Formatted a bit. Unfortunately, there are 109 columns in the table I'm appendeding to so the string of columns is quite long. Not sure if there's any way to format that better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing single quotes around every %s symbols. As Python will replace every %s by string values, it should be between single quotes in the SQL statement.

Comment: Didn't work. Same error message as before. Should I try converting the floats to a string in the tuple?

Comment: Just tried converting the floats to a string and still getting the same error.